# Merge 2 dataframes using conditions on "hour" and "min" of df1 in datetimes of df2

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, non-equi-join

I have a dataframe `df.sample` like this

```
id <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
date <- c("2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12",
          "2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-14","2018-11-14","2018-11-14",
          "2018-11-12")
hour <- c(8,8,9,9,13,13,16,6,7,19,7)
min <- c(47,59,6,18,22,36,12,32,12,21,47)
value <- c(70,70,86,86,86,74,81,77,79,83,91)
df.sample <- data.frame(id,date,hour,min,value,stringsAsFactors = F) 
df.sample$date <- as.Date(df.sample$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I have another data frame `df.state` like this

```
id <- c("A","A","A")
starttime <- c("2018-11-12 08:59:00","2018-11-14 06:24:17","2018-11-15 09:17:00")
endtime <- c("2018-11-12 15:57:00","2018-11-14 17:22:16","2018-11-15 12:17:32")
state <- c("Pass","Pass","Pass")

df.state <- data.frame(id,starttime,endtime,state,stringsAsFactors = F) 
df.state$starttime <- as.POSIXct(df.state$starttime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.state$endtime <- as.POSIXct(df.state$endtime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am trying to merge these 2 data frames based on a condition

if the `hour` and `min` in `df.sample` is within the `starttime` and `endtime` of `df.state`, then merge `state = Pass` in the `df.sample`.

For example, the row 2 in `df.sample` has `hour = 8`, `min = 59` and since it is within the `starttime = 2018-11-12 08:59:00` in `df.state`, the value `Pass` is added

Here is my **desired output**

```
   id       date hour min value state
    A 2018-11-12    8  47    70      
    A 2018-11-12    8  59    70  Pass
    A 2018-11-12    9   6    86  Pass
    A 2018-11-12    9  18    86  Pass
    A 2018-11-12   13  22    86  Pass
    A 2018-11-12   13  36    74  Pass
    A 2018-11-12   16  12    81      
    A 2018-11-14    6  32    77  Pass
    A 2018-11-14    7  12    79  Pass
    A 2018-11-14   19  21    83      
    A 2018-11-12    7  47    91
```

I am able to merge these 2 dataframes like this but not able to look up hour and min of df.sample in the starttime and endtime of df.state

```
library(tidyverse)
df.sample <- df.sample %>%
  left_join(df.state)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using non-equi join from `data.table` package is much faster and easier if you happen to have big data frames:** [Benchmark](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/talks/ArunSrinivasanUseR2016.pdf) | [Video](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable)

```r
library(data.table)

## convert both data.frames to data.tables by reference
setDT(df.sample)
setDT(df.state) 

## create a `time` column in df.sample 
df.sample[, time := as.POSIXct(paste0(date, " ", hour, ":", min, ":00"))]
## change column order
setcolorder(df.sample, c("id", "time"))

# join by id and time within start & end time limits
# "x." is used so we can refer to the column in other data.table explicitly
df.state[df.sample, .(id, time, date, hour, min, value, state = x.state), 
         on = .(id, starttime <= time, endtime >= time)]
#>     id                time       date hour min value state
#>  1:  A 2018-11-12 08:47:00 2018-11-12    8  47    70  <NA>
#>  2:  A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12    8  59    70  Pass
#>  3:  A 2018-11-12 09:06:00 2018-11-12    9   6    86  Pass
#>  4:  A 2018-11-12 09:18:00 2018-11-12    9  18    86  Pass
#>  5:  A 2018-11-12 13:22:00 2018-11-12   13  22    86  Pass
#>  6:  A 2018-11-12 13:36:00 2018-11-12   13  36    74  Pass
#>  7:  A 2018-11-12 16:12:00 2018-11-12   16  12    81  <NA>
#>  8:  A 2018-11-14 06:32:00 2018-11-14    6  32    77  Pass
#>  9:  A 2018-11-14 07:12:00 2018-11-14    7  12    79  Pass
#> 10:  A 2018-11-14 19:21:00 2018-11-14   19  21    83  <NA>
#> 11:  A 2018-11-12 07:47:00 2018-11-12    7  47    91  <NA>

### remove NA
df.state[df.sample, .(id, time, date, hour, min, value, state = x.state), 
         on = .(id, starttime <= time, endtime >= time), nomatch = 0L]
#>    id                time       date hour min value state
#> 1:  A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12    8  59    70  Pass
#> 2:  A 2018-11-12 09:06:00 2018-11-12    9   6    86  Pass
#> 3:  A 2018-11-12 09:18:00 2018-11-12    9  18    86  Pass
#> 4:  A 2018-11-12 13:22:00 2018-11-12   13  22    86  Pass
#> 5:  A 2018-11-12 13:36:00 2018-11-12   13  36    74  Pass
#> 6:  A 2018-11-14 06:32:00 2018-11-14    6  32    77  Pass
#> 7:  A 2018-11-14 07:12:00 2018-11-14    7  12    79  Pass
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49583674/786542) compare `dplyr` and `data.table` when performing non-equi-join for big data frames

Answer (score 1):

(Important prep note: `as.POSIXct` creates POSIXct values with the local time zone, whereas `lubridate::ymd` creates UTC times. You will get unexpected results if the time zones vary in your join below.)

```
df.state$starttime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df.state$starttime)
df.state$endtime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df.state$endtime)
```

This can be done with fuzzyjoin:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
df.sample %>%
  mutate(sample_time = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(date, hour, min))) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(df.state, 
                  by = c("id" = "id",
                         "sample_time" = "starttime",
                         "sample_time" = "endtime"),
                  match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))

   id.x       date hour min value         sample_time id.y           starttime             endtime state
1     A 2018-11-12    8  47    70 2018-11-12 08:47:00 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>  <NA>
2     A 2018-11-12    8  59    70 2018-11-12 08:59:00    A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12 15:57:00  Pass
3     A 2018-11-12    9   6    86 2018-11-12 09:06:00    A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12 15:57:00  Pass
4     A 2018-11-12    9  18    86 2018-11-12 09:18:00    A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12 15:57:00  Pass
5     A 2018-11-12   13  22    86 2018-11-12 13:22:00    A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12 15:57:00  Pass
6     A 2018-11-12   13  36    74 2018-11-12 13:36:00    A 2018-11-12 08:59:00 2018-11-12 15:57:00  Pass
7     A 2018-11-12   16  12    81 2018-11-12 16:12:00 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>  <NA>
8     A 2018-11-14    6  32    77 2018-11-14 06:32:00    A 2018-11-14 06:24:17 2018-11-14 17:22:16  Pass
9     A 2018-11-14    7  12    79 2018-11-14 07:12:00    A 2018-11-14 06:24:17 2018-11-14 17:22:16  Pass
10    A 2018-11-14   19  21    83 2018-11-14 19:21:00 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>  <NA>
11    A 2018-11-12    7  47    91 2018-11-12 07:47:00 <NA>                <NA>                <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by first adding a time column to your `df.sample` data.frame and then doing an evaluation based on your criteria using `sapply` and adding this result to `df.sample`

```
df.sample$time <- paste0(df.sample$date, ' ', sprintf('%02d', df.sample$hour),':', sprintf('%02d', df.sample$min), ':00')
df.sample$state <- sapply(df.sample$time, function(x) {
  after_start <- x >= df.state$starttime
  before_end <- x <= df.state$endtime
  y <- cbind(after_start, before_end)
  pass_check <- apply(y, 1, sum)
  if (2 %in% pass_check) {'PASS'} else {''}
  })

df.sample

   id       date hour min value                time state
1   A 2018-11-12    8  47    70 2018-11-12 08:47:00      
2   A 2018-11-12    8  59    70 2018-11-12 08:59:00  PASS
3   A 2018-11-12    9   6    86 2018-11-12 09:06:00  PASS
4   A 2018-11-12    9  18    86 2018-11-12 09:18:00  PASS
5   A 2018-11-12   13  22    86 2018-11-12 13:22:00  PASS
6   A 2018-11-12   13  36    74 2018-11-12 13:36:00  PASS
7   A 2018-11-12   16  12    81 2018-11-12 16:12:00      
8   A 2018-11-14    6  32    77 2018-11-14 06:32:00  PASS
9   A 2018-11-14    7  12    79 2018-11-14 07:12:00  PASS
10  A 2018-11-14   19  21    83 2018-11-14 19:21:00      
11  A 2018-11-12    7  47    91 2018-11-12 07:47:00
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is extract decimal hour from each dataframe that you supplied, so that I can ask whether or not a value is found within that decimal hour. But first, you have to merge the datasets based on id (assuming you have other ids) and date (assuming that there is only one state per day; or in other words one date exists per day in the df.state dataset).

```
id <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
date <- c("2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-12",
          "2018-11-12","2018-11-12","2018-11-14","2018-11-14","2018-11-14",
          "2018-11-12")
hour <- c(8,8,9,9,13,13,16,6,7,19,7)
min <- c(47,59,6,18,22,36,12,32,12,21,47)
value <- c(70,70,86,86,86,74,81,77,79,83,91)
df.sample <- data.frame(id,date,hour,min,value,stringsAsFactors = F) 
df.sample$date <- as.Date(df.sample$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")

df.sample$dec.hour <- as.numeric(df.sample$hour) +
  as.numeric(df.sample$min)/60
```

All I have added above are these last couple of lines to calculate a decimal hour from the hour and minute values that you have provided

```
id <- c("A","A","A")
starttime <- c("2018-11-12 08:59:00","2018-11-14 06:24:17","2018-11-15 09:17:00")
endtime <- c("2018-11-12 15:57:00","2018-11-14 17:22:16","2018-11-15 12:17:32")
state <- c("Pass","Pass","Pass")

df.state <- data.frame(id,starttime,endtime,state,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Here I have added a date vector (for the merge). I arbitrarily chose starttime, assuming the date for start and endtime are always the same.

```
df.state$date <- as.Date(df.state$starttime,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then I get a decimal hour for both the start and end times, on that date

```
t.str <- strptime(df.state$starttime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.state$dec.hour.start <- as.numeric(format(t.str, "%H")) +
  as.numeric(format(t.str, "%M"))/60

t.end <- strptime(df.state$endtime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.state$dec.hour.end <- as.numeric(format(t.end, "%H")) +
  as.numeric(format(t.end, "%M"))/60
```

merge the dataframes by id and date

```
df<-merge(df.sample, df.state, by=c("id","date"))
```

if the decimal hour of the sample is within the start or end decimal hour (for that date), then return a TRUE for state.

```
df<-df %>% 
  mutate(state = dec.hour >= dec.hour.start & dec.hour <= dec.hour.end)
```

Now if you want to get rid of all of these extra columns that I have created (so it looks like your desired output):

```
df<-df[,-c(6:8,10:11)]
```

Because df$state is logical, you have to first turn the values into characters if you want to change TRUE to pass and FALSE to a blank space:

```
df$state<-as.character(df$state)
df$state[df$state=="TRUE"]<-"pass"
df$state[df$state=="FALSE"]<-""
```

Take a look:

```
df

> df
   id       date hour min value state
1   A 2018-11-12    8  47    70      
2   A 2018-11-12    8  59    70  pass
3   A 2018-11-12    9   6    86  pass
4   A 2018-11-12    9  18    86  pass
5   A 2018-11-12   13  22    86  pass
6   A 2018-11-12   13  36    74  pass
7   A 2018-11-12   16  12    81      
8   A 2018-11-12    7  47    91      
9   A 2018-11-14    6  32    77  pass
10  A 2018-11-14    7  12    79  pass
11  A 2018-11-14   19  21    83
```

I used this post: [extract hours and seconds from POSIXct for plotting purposes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705328/extract-hours-and-seconds-from-posixct-for-plotting-purposes-in-r) to extract decimal hours
and this one: [Check to see if a value is within a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683444/check-to-see-if-a-value-is-within-a-range) to see whether or not your sample time was within your state time.